# How can I populate a DataGridView with data?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Background:
For a school assignment, I am making a program to track calories using C# and Windows Forms. This involves a local SQL database with two tables - Foods (a table of foods and calorie values) and Eating (a track of what the user has eaten, and when). I added a local database as instructed at [1] and I'm trying to display the food data (and eventually the eating data) using a DataGridView. I've looked at a lot of tutorials on this, each one saying different things, but none seem to work. The DGV is stuck looking like an empty grey box. There is definitely data in the table, but I don't know if the DGV is receiving any rows. I've taken a bunch of screenshots at [2].
I'm just looking for some way to populate the DGV with the data that works. Thanks.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2019

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/guehb.jpg

Comment: Hi Ideally, could you copy and paste the code into the question, people will take it and try and figure out the problem, trying to figure it out from screenshots is pretty tricky.

Comment: Also if the image gets deleted/moved people can use this as a resource for later

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have any columns declared in your DataGridView. You can do that in the designer with the property "Columns" or by code. The DataPropertyName from each column represents the column name from your table. In your case Id, Name, Calories...

Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms) for more.